# Puppeteer second Promise.all times out after trying to click td with class clickable-row

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to use Puppeteer to extract some data from a website. The script needs to input a form, submit it, click a clickable-row, then find the data inside another table. The first two steps work perfectly, but when trying to click the td with the class clickable row (or the a nested inside it), I get an odd result. If I'm running Chromium headless:false the link clicks but then all actions stop working on the page(in the code snipped I've tried inputing the form again for example). I've tried taking a screenshot after clicking the td, and it doesn't even take a shot of the third page, but rather the second (looks like the link has not been clicked), then after a while prompts the error

"{ TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
at Promise.then (/IMM2/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/LifecycleWatcher.js:106:111) name: 'TimeoutError' }"

I've also tried using the `await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle0',timeout:0});` but it didn't work either.

Here's the code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless : false });
  const listaFirme = `https://www.listafirme.ro/`
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(listaFirme, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  
  await page.type('input[name=searchfor]', '35629144');

    await Promise.all ([
     page.click('.input-group-btn .btn'),
     page.waitForNavigation(),
 ]).catch(e=> console.log(e))

await Promise.all ([
    page.click('.content table tbody tr:nth-child(even) .clickable-row a'),
    page.waitForNavigation(),
]).catch(e=> console.log(e))

await Promise.all ([
    page.type('input[name=searchfor]', '35629144'),
    page.waitForNavigation(),
]).catch(e=> console.log(e))

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Screenshots to clarify:

[First page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psPrR.png)

[Second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcO55.png)

I'm new to puppeteer so it's probably a silly mistake but I've been trying to solve it for a while now and it doesn't seem to have a solution that would work for me so far.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the second click opens a new page, so you need to catch this page instead of waiting for navigation on the current one:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const listaFirme = `https://www.listafirme.ro/`;
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(listaFirme, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

  await page.type('input[name=searchfor]', '35629144');

  await Promise.all([
    page.click('.input-group-btn .btn'),
    page.waitForNavigation(),
  ]).catch(e => console.log(e));

  const [newPage] = await Promise.all([
    getNewPage(),
    page.click('.content table tbody tr:nth-child(even) .clickable-row a'),
  ]).catch(e => console.log(e));

  await newPage.waitForSelector('input[name=searchfor]');
  await newPage.type('input[name=searchfor]', '35629144');

  await Promise.all([
    newPage.click('.input-group-btn .btn'),
    newPage.waitForNavigation(),
  ]).catch(e => console.log(e));

  console.log('Done');

  await browser.close();

  function getNewPage() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      browser.on('targetcreated', checkNewTarget);

      function checkNewTarget(target) {
        if (target.type() === 'page') {
          browser.off('targetcreated', checkNewTarget);
          resolve(target.page());
        }
      }
    });
  }
})();
```